# Java code does not compile when I add "print" function

Tags: printing, compilation

```
class FirstClass{
public static void main(String[] args) {

class XORShift64 {
      long x;
      public XORShift64(long seed) {
        x = seed==0 ? 0xdeadbeef : seed;
      }
      public long randomLong() {
        x ^= (x << 21); 
        x ^= (x >>> 35);
        x ^= (x << 4);
        system.out.print();
        return x;

      }

    }
```

}
}

So I have this code, to generate a random number using Xorshift, and it compiles fine, but when I add line "system.out.print();" it immediately shows an error, though I can't read what the error is.

Thanks for any help, I am just started java programming.

Comment: Maybe this is homework, but Random.nextLong() is a better way to generate a random long

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize the class name `System`, use the method `println()`, and pass the method an argument which you want printed out.

```
    System.out.println("something to print");
```

Comment: Thanks Ray, how i didn't think before :P

Comment: But as I understand random number must be x, right? But System.out.print(x); does not output any number for some reason.

Comment: @user1880405 `println(x)` not `print(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is fix for your program. Try to run this and let us know htis what exactly you want.

```
import java.util.Random;

class FirstClass {
    static long x;
    static Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            long randomInt = randomGenerator.nextLong();
            System.out.println("returned value :" + randomLong(randomInt));
        }
    }

    public static long randomLong(long xx) {
        xx ^= (xx << 21);
        xx ^= (xx >>> 35);
        xx ^= (xx << 4);
        System.out.println("Inside Method: " + xx);
        return xx;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks smit, but how do I generate random number? It always shows 0

Comment: I updated the answer. Now try this. It will generate 100 random numbers as you can see in for loop.

Comment: Its almost like spoon feeding. Please try first by your own otherwise you wont be able learn anything.